# Google Appengine Cursors

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-search-api

I'm using both `ndb` and `search-api` queries in my python appengine project.

The only official docs on cursors I can find:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/query-cursors
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/cursorclass

Following things are unclear for me:

1. What is cursor time-to-live ? Can I expose year-old cursors ?
2. How would cursor pagination behave in case items are added/removed from original collection? (+ if cursor points to particular record, what happens if this record no longer exists?)
3. How does query ordering affect above?
4. Are there any fundamental differences between ndb and search-api cursors?

Comment: some of these are in the in-depth appengine articles in their blog. agree it should be in the docs too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm answering from `ndb` perspective, I haven't use the search API. All quotes are from your first link.

For 1 and 3 (as ordering is considered part of the original query from cursors perspective):

> To retrieve additional results from the point of the cursor, the
>   application prepares a similar query with the same entity kind,
>   filters, and sort orders, and passes the cursor to the query's
>   with_cursor() method before performing the retrieval

So it doesn't really matter how old the cursor is (i.e. how old its query is) since its **original query** must be restored for the cursor to be obtained.

For 2:

> Cursors and data updates
>
> The cursor's position is defined as the location in the result list
>   after the last result returned. A cursor is not a relative position in
>   the list (it's not an offset); it's a marker to which Cloud Datastore
>   can jump when starting an index scan for results. If the results for a
>   query change between uses of a cursor, the query notices only changes
>   that occur in results after the cursor. If a new result appears before
>   the cursor's position for the query, it will not be returned when the
>   results after the cursor are fetched. Similarly, if an entity is no
>   longer a result for a query but had appeared before the cursor, the
>   results that appear after the cursor do not change. If the last result
>   returned is removed from the result set, the cursor still knows how to
>   locate the next result.
>
> When retrieving query results, you can use both a start cursor and an
>   end cursor to return a continuous group of results from Cloud
>   Datastore. When using a start and end cursor to retrieve the results,
>   you are not guaranteed that the size of the results will be the same
>   as when you generated the cursors. Entities may be added or deleted
>   from Cloud Datastore between the time the cursors are generated and
>   when they are used in a query.

The Java equivalent page at [Limitations of cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/query-cursors#limitations_of_cursors) mentions some errors that can be raised for inconsistencies:

> New App Engine releases might change internal implementation details,
>   invalidating cursors that depend on them. If an application attempts
>   to use a cursor that is no longer valid, Cloud Datastore raises an
>   `IllegalArgumentException` (low-level API), `JDOFatalUserException`
>   (JDO), or `PersistenceException` (JPA).

I *suspect* Python would be raising some similar errors as well.

Comment: Great question, and great answer.  Learned something today. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it does not answer all sub-questions, also search-api is not covered at all